# Disable SNI in a modern browser

Tags: ssl, sni

Is there a way to temporarily disable SNI in a modern browser?

E.g. to test a website availability for older clients. (Should one worry about them since POODLE?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the best way to test availability for older clients is to actually try out older clients. Microsoft provides VM images for browser compatibility testing at https://www.modern.ie/, which probably covers most of the desktop-based legacy clients, at least.

Another great resource for testing web site SSL/TLS compatibility in general is the [Qualys SSL Server Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/), which tries all the protocols and gives a simulation of what cipher suites browsers will be negotiating, as well as other useful information.

I'm not aware of any specific modern browser setting for disabling SNI specifically. Probably it'd open up a whole bunch of code paths that would need testing for not really any benefit, and support for it is probably deep within whatever library the browser is using for SSL/TLS support.